# Update Pivot Table Source Data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sorry that this seems to be a duplicate question, but I've tried 2 separate methods and neither work. Here's the first:

```
Set wbGen = ThisWorkbook
Set wsPivot = wbGen.Sheets("Pivot")
Set rData = wbGen.Sheets("Fan Data").Range("A1")
Set rData = Range(rData, rData.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
NewRange = wbGen.Sheets("Fan Data").Name & "!" & _
    rData.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
wsPivot.PivotTables("FanPivot").ChangePivotCache _
    wsPivot.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)
```

And here's the second:

```
Set wbGen = ThisWorkbook
Set wsPivot = wbGen.Sheets("Pivot")
Set rData = wbGen.Sheets("Fan Data").Range("A1")
Set rData = Range(rData, rData.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
wsPivot.PivotTables("FanPivot").ChangePivotCache _
    wsPivot.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rData)
```

Both methods snag on the last line and return

> Run Time Error 438: Object doesn't support method or property

Comment: Which line errors out?

Comment: @JohnyL the last line in both cases

Comment: Use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `wsPivot`

Answer (score 0):

```
Set wbGen = ThisWorkbook
Set wsPivot = wbGen.Sheets("Pivot")
Set rData = wbGen.Sheets("Fan Data").Range("A1")
Set rData = Range(rData, rData.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
wsPivot.PivotTables("FanPivot").ChangePivotCache _
    wbGen.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rData)
```